# Tools to mesure perfomance of salesforce experience site

Tags: community, lightning-experience, force.com-sites, site.com

I have a partner community and need to measure performance for all pages as a logged user and as a guest.
I found some topics from Salesforce on how to measure lightning pages
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-experience-performance-optimization/measure-lightning-experience-performance-and-experience-page-time-ept
in salesforce and increase community performance https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exp_cloud_plan_performance_scale.htm&type=5 ,but I need something like a performance report for my site

Answer (score 0):

This [Salesforce Page Optimizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-page-optimizer/alkcnclapbnefkodhbkpifdkceldogka) Chrome extension works for experiences and provides detailed information and advice for each of your pages. That then allows you to focus your optimisation efforts, including being able to do before/after speed comparisons.

[image: exaple output]

Comment: I need something like a report to track the whole site performance

Comment: @Alex OK, so probably best to search broadly i.e. not just in the Salesforce world.